# Dict lookup in python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Are the following two expressions equivalent?

```
# python
PLAN_TO_COST_PER_UNIT.get(planType, value_if_empty)

# javascript
PLAN_TO_COST_PER_UNIT[planType] || value_if_empty;
```

If not, what would be the closest equivalent in javasript to doing the above python dict lookup?

Comment: No, since if the value in the JavaScript version exists, but is `null`, it will take `value_if_empty` as well.

Comment: Not just for ``null``, but for any ``falsey`` values, such as ``""``, ``false``, ``0``, ``Nan``, ``null`` or ``undefined``.

Comment: It would make more sense to just use a JS `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

**Python**. In Python if you write:

```
PLAN_TO_COST_PER_UNIT.get(planType, value_if_empty)
```

This means that if the `planType` key exists, that value is returned, regardless what that value is. In case it can not be found `value_if_empty` is returned.

For example:

```
>>> a = {'key': 0}
>>> a.get('key', 1425)
0
```

**JavaScript**. Your JavaScript version does not doe that: it fetches the value for the key, and in case no such key exists, `undefined` is returned. Then you use `||` such that if the "truthiness" of the result is `false`, it takes the right operand (`value_if_empty`).

If you however would construct an object where the value is `0`, then it would still take the `value_if_empty`, like:

```
> a = {key: 0}
{ key: 0 }
> a['key'] || 1425
1425
```

I think the closest to the Python version is making a membership check:

```
function tryget(obj, key, missing) {
    if(key in obj) {
        return obj[key];
    }
    else {
        return missing;
    }
}
```

Then we thus can call it with `tryget({a: 0}, 'a', 1425)`.

Comment: thanks for this clear explanation -- so then what would be the javascript to do the python equivalent?

Comment: What about `planType in PLAN_TO_COST_PER_UNIT ? PLAN_TO_COST_PER_UNIT[planType] : value_if_empty`?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do some sort of check yourself

One method is to define a `get` function and use that

e.g.

```
function get(object, key, default_value) {
    var result = object[key];
    return (typeof result !== "undefined") ? result : default_value;
}
```

Comment: That still does the wrong thing if an object actually has `undefined` as a property value.

Comment: It would make more sense to check if the property exists, e.g. with ``hasOwnProperty``.